# How to close/open all brackets in sublime text 3?

Tags: ubuntu, sublime-text-3

I am working on some sass files and sometimes I need to close all the enclosing brackets to find where is the missing bracket or the extra one:

[image]

So how can I close/open all pairs of brackets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sublime Text doesn't remember code folds within code folds, so there isn't a way to do what you're asking. Check out Edit>Code Folding for all the built in options available to you.

There are plugins, like [BracketHighlighter](https://facelessuser.github.io/BracketHighlighter/), which would help you find missing/extra brackets.

You could also use [SublimeLinter](http://sublimelinter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), with a sass plugin,

Comment: Bracket Highlighter would be the best way, I agree.

Answer (score 0):

In new versions of Sublime Text (*currently* `Version 3.2.2 Build 3211`), there is options to fold the code for various levels. There is 9 levels, i suppose it is enough for you and for anyone like you.

```
Edit > Code Folding > [select Fold Level]
```